# Writing to serial usb to control an Ardunio from an Ubuntu computer

Tags: arduino

I want to control and Ardunio by writing bytes to it in the same way I would use the serial monitor on my laptop. 
How could one accomplish this?

Comment: You want to control an Arduino from a USB port? You use the serial port on your laptop to control it right now?

Comment: I want to use a script on an ubuntu computer to control it through USB.

Answer (score 1):

You can by using pySerial.

This will allow a console based python script (or a python GUI program even) to listen/talk to you Arduino.

That's the route I took to make my generic Arduino DIY CNC machine.
If your interested you can check it out at: http://emc2arduino.wordpress.com/